# Unity android permissions removed but still present in apk

Tags: android, xml, unity-game-engine, manifest

I'm using Unity 2022.3.8f1.

```html
<manifest ... xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    ...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" tools:node="remove" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

I made my manifest as the code shows but still the permission is set on the built apk.
Did the method change or something?
How to do it now?

tried removing permission in manifest file

Comment: That's how we remove permissions. Make sure you're doing it in both the launcher and main manifests.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Tanks Retired Ninja!
The problem was I had no idea that I must set the launcher manifest.
I believe that this wasn't necessary in older version.
Anyways Thanks again!

Comment: I think they changed it in 2020.x. Was a surprise to me at the time too.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).